# calling a method on an object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```
const info = {
  name: 'Steve',
  phone: 20655564,
  email: 'SJ@yahoo.com',
  sayName: function(){
    console.log('Hello I am ' + info.name);
  },
};
```

I made a random object and was using a different function to call that objects method.

```
function invokeMethod(object, method) {
  // method is a string that contains the name of a method on the object
  // invoke this method
  // nothing needs to be returned
  const func = object[method]
  object.func();

}

invokeMethod(info, 'sayName');
```

However, when I when I run the invokeMethod function above I get the error func is not a function. However, when I run

```
return func
```

as a test I get 
`[function]`

trying to figure out how to get it to do the sayName method

Comment: why can't you pass in the function instead of the object and method name?

Comment: `object[method]();` or `func.call(object);`

Answer (score 4):

There is a error at line `object.func();`

It should be `func.call(object);` instead of `object.func();`
Or you should call it directly `object[method]()`

```js
const info = {
  name: 'Steve',
  phone: 20655564,
  email: 'SJ@yahoo.com',
  sayName: function(){
    console.log('Hello I am ' + info.name);
  },
};


function invokeMethod(object, method) {
  // method is a string that contains the name of a method on the object
  // invoke this method
  // nothing needs to be returned
  const func = object[method]
  func.call(object);

}

invokeMethod(info, 'sayName');
```

Comment: this messes up `this` in the inner function if it is not explicitly bound. It's better to do `object[method]();`, or maybe `func.call(object);`.